# Button to send http to NodeJS/Express backend to execute a function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, express

I have a button in my frontend, and am using nodejs and express on my server-side backend. I have a function (essentially controlling Philips Hue API) on the backend, and I would like it to be executed when the button is clicked, through a http request.

I have tried different methods. the backend script for the Philips Hue controls work independently when i extract it and run it in git bash. I think there's some conceptual or coding errors on end.

Html Button

```
<button id="pulse" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Pulsing Lights</button>
```

Client side JS

```
const pulseButton = document.getElementById("pulse");
pulseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fetch('/huePulseLight', {method: 'POST'})
    .then(function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
        console.log('Click was recorded');
        return;
      }
      throw new Error('Request failed.');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Backend/Server Side JS

```
const port = 3000;
const server = http.Server(app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
    console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
});


const app = express();

pulseLight = lightState.create().on().colorLoop();

function setPulseLight() {
  nodeHueapi.setLightState(1, pulseLight, function (err, lights) {
    if (err) throw err;
    displayResult(lights);
  });

  nodeHueapi.setLightState(2, pulseLight, function (err, lights) {
    if (err) throw err;
    displayResult(lights);
  });

  nodeHueapi.setLightState(3, pulseLight, function (err, lights) {
    if (err) throw err;
    displayResult(lights);
  });
}

app.post('/huePulseLight', function(req, res){
console.log("Pulse Light Set");
setPulseLight();
});
```

Comment: is there any response to the api when you use postman?

Comment: nope. i think the endpoints are ok though. i suspect the problem lies with the http call.

Answer (score 2):

**Isolate the problem**. Make sure both your server and browser consoles are communicating properly before adding anything else. This is more-or-less the minimum code for the client and server to communicate. Run `node server.js` in `test`, navigate to `localhost:3000`, click the text, observe the console outputs.

`test/server.js`

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

// make index.html accessible to clients
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.post('/huePulseLight', function(request, response){
  console.log("Pulse Light Set");
  response.send("Click Recorded")
});

app.listen(3000)
```

`test/public/index.html`

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  </body>
    <p id="pulse">foo</p>

    <script>      
      const pulseButton = document.getElementById("pulse")

      pulseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        fetch('/huePulseLight', {method: 'POST'})
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(text => console.log(text))
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no it does not. i think the http request is done incorrectly, would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `app.listen(PORT)` on your server.

Also, you're not sending back anything from the server to the client, that might cause the client to keep the connection open with the server and your fetch promise will never resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I have the port config in front. Just didn't want to flood. Amended to reflect.

Comment: If you're running your server on your local machine on port 3000, have you tried changing your fetch URI parameter to `localhost:3000/huePulseLight`